# AVAsset to CIDetectorImageOrientation

Tags: ios, swift

I want to run face detection using CoreImage on every frame in an `AVAsset` and to do that, I need the `CIDetectorImageOrientation` for every sample buffer in that asset.

The problem is, if I convert a `CMSampleBuffer` to a `UIImage` and translate that image to exif orientation using:

```
var exifOrientation: UInt32 {
    switch self.imageOrientation {
    case .Up: return 1
    case .Down: return 3
    case .Left: return 8
    case .Right: return 6
    case .UpMirrored: return 2
    case .DownMirrored: return 4
    case .LeftMirrored: return 5
    case .RightMirrored: return 7
    }
}
```

the orientation is always `.Up`, regardless of how the video was taken (front vs back camera) or the orientation the video was taken in.

How can I properly get the `CIDetectorImageOrientation` for a `CMSampleBuffer`?

Answer (score -1):

You need to get the orientation of the video track of that asset. This orientation will be the same for every frame.
Here's a roughly how you'd do it in Objective C.

```
AVAssetTrack *videoTrack =[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo].firstObject;
CGSize size = [videoTrack naturalSize];
CGAffineTransform preferredTransform = [videoTrack preferredTransform];

if (size.width == preferredTransform.tx && size.height == preferredTransform.ty) {
  return kCGImagePropertyOrientationRight;
} else if (preferredTransform.tx == 0 && preferredTransform.ty == 0) {
  return kCGImagePropertyOrientationUpLeft;
} else if (preferredTransform.tx == 0 && preferredTransform.ty == size.width) {
  return kCGImagePropertyOrientationDown;
}
...
```